# chrome debug missing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm doing some debugging on my site that has multiple scripts running. When I debug in firefox using firebug, the specific script I'm working on, (basically a series of jQuery listeners), shows up, breakpoints work - awesome. When I debug in chrome though, the script shows up under resources, but not under scripts. I can't put in breakpoints! I'm not a big fan of firebug, and I would really prefer to use chrome's debugger.

I'm not 100% where the problem is. It could be chrome (that's where I'm leaning), but I am debugging the script, so it's nowhere near stable enough to rule out. (The functions in the listeners aren't breaking in firebug)

**Q:** How does chrome decide to put something in the scripts tab and thereby allow debugging? and does it ever get this wrong and exclude scripts that run?

Comment: Have you tried popping the inspector out of the page, and reloading it with Command/Ctrl - R?

Comment: yeah - that's how I like to do debug in chrome

Answer (score 2):

DevTools may omit scripts that are fully collected at some moment of time. For example if you script does not have any function, it will be fully collected once it ran.
Could it be your case?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, imported scripts are put in a separate script pane whereas scripts embedded in the webpage are displayed in the webpage pane (yourpage.html).  You can still access the webpage pane for debugging most of the time.  I haven't ever had anything like the problem you're describing though, so I may not understand your issue.